Run Powershell with parameters from batch file
For convenience of use, I need to put my powershell script in a bat file. The bat file content is as follows:
# 2>NUL & @CLS & PUSHD "%~dp0" & powershell -COMMAND "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-windowstyle hidden -nol -nop -ep bypass ""[IO.File]::ReadAllText(''%~f0'')|iex""'"
# powershell script

However, in the powershell script, I need to get the path of the bat file. I know I can get the full path by 'SET "batFilePath=%~f0"'... but I don't know what I should do next to be able to pass in and use the batFilePath argument in the powershell script. Please help me, thank you very much.
P/s: It's not that I'm lazy, I tried looking for similar topics, but the answers are all very confusing to me, I'm not sure what to do in my case. Excuse me.

Sounds like it'd be much more convenient to not use a bat file. What is the real reason? What problem occurs when you don't store your PowerShell script in a batch file?

You have the arguments inside single quotes instead of double quotes.

@MathiasR.Jessen I created a small software and want to share it with friends who are not knowledgeable about how to use code. I want everything to be as simple as possible for them, just click and run. I tried packaging the exe with PS2EXE but always got false positives from AV, so I decided to create a bat file. If you're interested, I'll post the source code on GitHub and hope you can give me some feedback. Thank you.

If you run 'SET "batFilePath=%~f0"' in cmd you can access the var in powershell by running '$env:batFilePath'.
Here is an example code
# 2>NUL & @CLS & SET "batFilePath=%~f0" & powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ""-windowstyle hidden -nol -nop  Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Path $env:batFilePath -Raw)"""

Update:
To pass $batFilePath to the now PowerShell process you can use this code
# 2>NUL & @CLS & SET "batFilePath=%~f0" & powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command `$batFilePath='$env:batFilePath'; Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Path $env:batFilePath -Raw)\"" & exit

Actually you don't need to set 'batFilePath' in cmd you can simply use '~f0' like this
# 2>NUL & @CLS & powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command `$batFilePath='%~f0'; Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Path %~f0 -Raw)\"" & exit


Thanks a lot.  But I want to use $batFilePath inside a powershell script, for example to register Windows startup "New-ItemProperty -Path $regKeyPath -Name $regKeyName -Value $batFilePath -PropertyType String -Force".  So how can I pass the $batFilePath argument in?  Please just help me.

@NqHai what don't you understand about environmental variables? Environmental variables are accessed just like the example is given: $env:batFilePath

@Squashman Yes, my knowledge is very limited. I tried testing the code using the bat file content as follows: #2>NUL... (remove -windowstyle hidden and add -noexit).  2nd line: Write-Host "Hello $env:batFilePath". But I only get "Hello". I don't know any way to pass $env:batFilePath to the script.

@yy Thank you very much for patiently guiding me, I understood through your example.  Have a good day!


Your task is a tricky one, because it requires communicating a value to a process that is launched with elevation (is launched with administrative privileges), using
Start-Process -Verb RunAs.
You can not use environment variables in this case, because an elevated process does not inherit the caller's environment variables:[1]

Therefore, you have to "bake" the value(s) of interest into the (implied) -Command argument that is passed to the elevated powershell.exe instance, which can get tricky in terms of quoting and escaping.

Additionally, in Windows PowerShell, an elevated process does not inherit the caller's working directory and defaults to C:\Windows\System32; fortunately, this problem has been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7.


The following is a modified version of your hybrid batch file that - visibly - demonstrates defining (shell-only) variable $batFilePath with the originating batch file's full path (%~f0) and also changing to the caller's working directory (%~dp0) first, using Set-Location:
<# ::
@echo off & setlocal
powershell -NoProfile Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoExit -WindowStyle Normal -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Set-Location \\\"%~dp0\\"; $batFilePath = \\\"%~f0\\\"; Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw \\\"%~f0\\\")'
exit /b
#>

# PowerShell code goes below; it is executed in the context of an 
# elevated PowerShell session based on the `powershell` call above.

[pscustomobject] @{
  batFilePath = $batFilePath
  workingDir = $PWD
}

That is, the above creates an elevated, visible, stay-open PowerShell instance that demonstrates that (a) the working directory is the same as the caller's and (b) that variable $batFilePath reflects the original batch file's full path.
Note:

%~f0 and %~dp0 are used to refer to the calling batch file's full file path and the full directory path in which it resides, using cmd.exe's argument-expansion syntax, as described in the output from cmd /c call /?

The PowerShell CLI, with -Command / -c, which is the implied parameter in Windows PowerShell's CLI, powershell.exe, requires " chars. to be escaped as \" in order to be passed through verbatim as part of the code.

By contrast, pwsh, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI defaults to -File and requires explicit use of -Command / -c in order to pass PowerShell source code as an argument. The same escaping rules apply there, though pwsh.exe on Windows also accepts "" as an escaped ", which is actually preferable when calling from cmd.exe (batch files) so as to avoid running afoul of cmd.exe's syntax.


Since there is a nested powershell.exe call involved, the above uses \\\" to escape the " chars. to ultimately pass to the nested, elevated powershell.exe instance. However, since %~dp0 always expands to a directory path with a trailing \, it is followed by only \\" above.



[1] Additionally, even explicitly trying to pass an environment to an elevated process is prevented by the underlying .NET APIs.
By contrast, a directly launched PowerShell instance (or one launched with Start-Process but without -Verb RunAs) implicitly inherits all of the caller's environment variables, and since using the SET statement in a batch file to define a variable invariably creates an environment variable, such a PowerShell instance automatically sees such variables, using $env: namespace variable notation - see the conceptual about_Environment_Variables help topic.
E.g., calling SET FOO=bar in the calling batch file before invoking the PowerShell CLI allows the latter to reference said variable('s value) as $env:FOO.
